# R^2 for mixed effect models (both generalized linear and additive)

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, model-selection, gamm4

I have seen from several discussion threads that there are a few ways of calculating R^2 for LMMs and GLMMs - albeit with a caveat for GLMM being that the existing methods work for only gaussian distribution (for example [here](http://jonlefcheck.net/2013/03/13/r2-for-linear-mixed-effects-models/)).

1. Is there a method for GLMM that is less sensitive to the distribution family?
2. Are there methods that can be used with Generalized additive models (for instance `gamm4` class of models, `lme4`)

There is probably no simple answer for these questions, but suggestions on workarounds and the associated caveats would be great.

Comment: The best workaround is to forget about R^2 for mixed models :)

Comment: If the interpretation is $R^2 = 1- \frac{\sum (y_i - \hat y_i)^2}{\sum (y_i - \bar y)^2}$, then one can calculate this for any model.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in checking-out [**performance**](https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/r2.html)'s `r2()` family of functions, that works with mixed models. For gamm4, support should be implemented soon (see [this thread](https://github.com/easystats/performance/issues/198)).